# How to make a simple plus one voting system in code igniter

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am trying to make a plus one voting system with jquery on my website. I have the html/css structure built. I have a thumb image that when hovered over, turns green, when someone clicks it, I want it to add a +1 and keep incrementing as people keep hitting it.

Here is what it looks like:[image]

So when someone hits it, I want it to add the numbers to the right of the plus sign. Here is my html structure.

```
echo "<div id='thumb_holder'>";
echo "<div id='thumb_report'>";
echo "<a href='mailto:info@cysticlife.org'>";
echo "&#149 report";
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div  class= 'thumb_counter'>";
echo "+";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='thumb_thumb'>";
echo "<!--PHP STUFF-->";
echo "<a class='myButtonLink' href=''></a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Any suggestions,guidance, or links to tutorials on how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to use `ajax`

Comment: How proficient are you on PHP, MYSQL, AJAX, JQUERY? You might need them all for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you dont have to echo all your html code, just use `<?php ?>` when you need it for dynamic content. as dianuj suggested you need to use ajax. make an ajax call using jquery (for simplicity sake) to your ajax handling public function, handle it there (for example using an id and increment a counter) and then return some data to the client. If the ajax request succeeds update the counter using javascript.

i'll give you an example taken from my app

codeigniter part, inside the controller
i handle a post that provides an imageid and the userid to check their permissions and echo
a response. for more complex app you should use json for various reasons.

```
public function changeImage(){
   if ($this->input->post('imageid')){
   .... handle imageid and userid, check for permissions, query the database..
   ...construct a $response...
   echo $response;
   }
}
```

in javascript i use something like this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
```

..prepare a mydata array..

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>pathtocontroller/changeImage",
                data: mydata,

                success: function(data){
                        //update your counter here
                }

        });
```

});

i think that answers your general question on a way to do this.